# React-Native couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so above react native version 60+

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-studio

If anybody facing this issue then use bellow steps and solve this:

1. build.gradle(Project)

add bellow code in repositories

```
maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
```

2. build.gradle(app)
   a. add below code on top:

   project.ext.react = [
   enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
   ]
   def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
   def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

b. add below code in dependencies:

```
if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)